# Oracle query to list all occurrences of a string from CLOB field

Tags: regex, oracle, loops, clob

I have a CLOB field in my Oracle table and would like to extract all occurrences of the string which matches the pattern 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint'.

**Example - **

|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011|
|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint023|
|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint086|
|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint100|

I used the below query to get all occurrences of the string 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint' in CLOB data for the above-provided example. The query is able to get all 4 occurrences but displays only the first occurrence of the string in all 4 rows.

**Query -**

**select objectid, REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint[^|]+', 1,1) column1 from perftest.NRS_DATASOURCEDATA_A_Test  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint')  ) as sys.odcinumberlist))**

**Actual Result -**

| objectid | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 |

**Expected Result -**

| objectid | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint023 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint086 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some of your query? But the issue is the second '1' in regexp_substr. Here's the description of the 4th arg [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html):

> occurrence is a positive integer indicating which occurrence of pattern in source_char Oracle should search for. The default is 1, meaning that Oracle searches for the first occurrence of pattern.

So regexp_count found 4 instances, but each time regexp_substr gets the first one. You'll want to change it from `1` to `level`, so the regexp_substr is looking at the same occurrence as regexp_count for each row.

Without the rest of the query, I can't say for sure, but I think `level` probably got re-aliased to `column_value` by the table/cast/multiset statement, so I think that's probably what you want.

```
select objectid, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint[^|]+', 1,column_value) column1  
from test_table 
cross join  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual  
                 connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint')
... more query, probably? maybe just ")))" ...
```

As a side note, you can maybe rewrite the table/cast/multiset to a simpler inline view - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598697/table-cast-multiset-vs-subquery-in-from-clause).

--EDIT--

Ok, it sounds like your clob is actually structured data. If you know that there are 3 fields in each row, like this:

| RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrintXXX | F99999999 | (blank) |
| --- | --- | --- |

then the `column_value` that you get back from the cross-join will basically be your row number. Your column2 regexp_substr is now just looking for any field - so if you want the second column, it'll be (row number)*(number of columns)+(the column you want, which is 2). In other words:

`(column_value-1)*3+2` will give you column 2. Change the 2 to a 3 if you want column 3.

If your data actually has 4 columns, you'll need to change the 3 to a 4.

```
select objectid, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint[^\|]+', 1,column_value) column1, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '([^\|]+)', 1, (column_value-1)*3+2) AS column2,
    column_value 
from test_table 
cross join 
    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint') ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
```

Comment: Thank you kfinity for your comments. I was able to extract all the occurrences after changing from '1' to 'column_value'. On a side note, I face the same issue (getting only the first value) while trying to pull the next value 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint' (separated by |) from the clob data.

Comment: Query used ---- select objectid, REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint[^\|]+', 1,column_value) column1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '([^\|]+)', 1, 3) AS column2 from perftest.NRS_DATASOURCEDATA_A_Test  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint')  ) as sys.odcinumberlist))

Comment: Sample DATA -|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010|F28028079| |RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011|F28028081| |RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013F28028007| |RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint014|F28028008|

Comment: @AR91 - ok, edited my answer with more info.